# How To Rotate\Animate Parent Objects?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I want to make this monkey spinning on its own rotation but something is off. I ´parented´ everything to the body, so it is the object that I´m creating the keyframes on.

When I move  <kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, he doesn´t move. Does anyone know what can it possibly be? It only works then I move it with <kbd>G</kbd>, because when I try to scale it, nothing happens either.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the N panel (on the right) > Item, have you locked Rotation?

Comment: no, it´s all unlocked

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=M9bvvnwJ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/M9bvvnwJ/)

Answer (score 0):

You've enabled the *Locations* option, disable it:

[image]